# Extjs : Reflect the change in browser

Tags: java, html, tomcat, extjs, extjs5

I am using Extjs 5.

Here is the code i am using

```
Ext.application({
name : 'MyApp',

launch : function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
        width : 200,
        height : 150,
        bodyPadding : 5,
        title : 'Hello World',
        html : 'Hello <b>World</b>...'
    });
}
});
```

Here i am using server.

What i exactly wants if i change my code and save the file , so that it will reflect on the browser on simple refresh i.e F5 (Right now i need to run the server again to see the changes).

Setting of tomcat

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem could be that your .js files are stored in the cache and when you refresh, the browser never load the lastest version of the file.

Try to use Chrome and its debugger(F12) to check if the changes you made in eclipse actually show up in the browser. And instead of F5, right click(when debugger active) in the refresh button and select the third option ("Clean the cache....").

Seeing your images, seems that your server configuration looks good.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your configuration because server only delivers javascript files to the client (browser) to execute. Would it be possible that server caches old version of files? Give us more details to advise you more spot on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse IDE, you should enable Build Automatically Option from project Menu to track the javascript changes.